# XSLT Keys, nested or multiple

Tags: xml, xslt, muenchian-grouping

Here is my xml (greatly simplified and shortened, in my real deal there are 100s of 'movie' elements)

```
<mediaList>
    <movie>
        <title>Hugo</title>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Children and Family</genre>
            <subGenre>Book Characters</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Family Adventures</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Family Dramas</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Drama</genre>
            <subGenre>Family Dramas</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>Vanishing Point</title>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Action and Adventure</genre>
            <subGenre>Action Classics</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Action Thrillers</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Thrillers</genre>
            <subGenre>Action Thrillers</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>White Lightning</title>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Action and Adventure</genre>
            <subGenre>Crime Action</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Sports and Fitness</genre>
            <subGenre>Motorsports</subGenre>
            <subSubGenre>Auto Racing</subSubGenre>
        </genreWrap>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>Kon-Tiki</title>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Action and Adventure</genre>
            <subGenre>Adventures</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Foreign Action and Adventure</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Drama</genre>
            <subGenre>Dramas Based on Real Life</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Family Dramas</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Period Pieces</subGenre>
            <subSubGenre>20th Century Period Pieces</subSubGenre>
        </genreWrap>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Foreign</genre>
            <subGenre>Foreign Action and Adventure</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Foreign Dramas</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Foreign Languages</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Foreign Regions</subGenre>
            <subSubGenre>Norwegian Language</subSubGenre>
            <subSubGenre>Scandinavia</subSubGenre>
        </genreWrap>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>Mummy, The</title>
        <director>Stephen Sommers</director>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Action and Adventure</genre>
            <subGenre>Action Thrillers</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Adventures</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Horror</genre>
            <subGenre>Monsters</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Thrillers</genre>
            <subGenre>Action Thrillers</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Supernatural Thrillers</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
    </movie>
</mediaList>
```

I've removed everything but the titles and genres from this example because that's the part that's tripping me up. I'm trying to put them into a good format to be used as a navigatable tool bar

something like this:

```
                <ul>
                    <li>Action and Adventures
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                               Action Classics
                            </li>
                             <li>
                               Action Thrillers
                             </li>
                             <li>
                               Adventures
                             </li>
                             <li>
                               Crime Action
                             </li>
                             <li>
                               Foreign Action and Adventure
                             </li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                    <li>Children and Family
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                               Book Characters
                            </li>
                             <li>
                               Family Adventures 
                             </li>
                             <li>
                               Family Dramas
                             </li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
```

etc. etc. every "genre" gets an `<li>` and all its subGenre's are placed into a new `<ul>` below it, if there's a subSubGenre (like with Kon-Tiki) it just extends one more level.

I've been reading up on keys and Muenchian Grouping --

I have this key at the top of my XSL file

```
<xsl:key name="movieByGenre" match="genre" use="."/>
```

and understand that it indexes ever genre element by the name I've given them, and then by using

```
select="movie//*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('movieByGenre', .)[1])]"
```

in an `<xsl:for-each>` or `<xsl:apply-templates>` I can do whatever I'd like to every genre. That's working fine.

It's getting the subGenres to appear under each that's killing me.

I have this, which is WRONG but I can't figure out how to make it right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
            <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:key name="keyGenre" match="genre" use="."/>    
        <xsl:key name="keySubGenre" match="subGenre" use="../genre"/> 

        <xsl:template match="mediaList">
            <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="movie//*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyGenre', .)[1])]">  
                      <xsl:sort order="ascending"/>
                            <li>
                   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                 <ul>
                    <li>
<xsl:for-each select="movie//*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keySubGenre', .)[1])]">
                                <xsl:sort order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</li>
    </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
</li>
                </xsl:for-each>
     </ul>
    </xsl:template>
          </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would be happy to accept an xsl 2.0 solution if you can explain how it's working! But i have a firmer grasp on 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you want to handle the subSubGenres - they don't appear to be nested under subGenres. For the first two levels, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="genre" match="genre" use="."/>  
<xsl:key name="subGenre-by-genre" match="subGenre" use="../genre"/> 
<xsl:key name="subGenre" match="subGenre" use="concat(../genre, '|', .)"/> 

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ul>
        <!-- for each distinct genre ... -->
        <xsl:for-each select="mediaList/movie/genreWrap/genre[generate-id()=generate-id(key('genre', .)[1])]">  
            <xsl:sort/>
            <li>
                <xsl:variable name="genre" select="." />
                <xsl:value-of select="$genre"/>
                <ul>
                    <!-- ... get the list of the relevant sub-genres ... -->
                    <xsl:variable name="mySubGenres" select="key('subGenre-by-genre', .)" />
                    <!-- ... and de-dupe it -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="$mySubGenres[generate-id()=generate-id(key('subGenre', concat($genre, '|', .))[1])]">
                        <xsl:sort/>
                        <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: wow! so fast! thanks for that -- as for subSubGenre, they are ALWAYS immediately following the subGenre that they sub so would adding a key like, <xsl:key name="subSubGenre match="subsubGenre" use="preceeding-sibling::subGenre[1]"> work?

Comment: I think so (I'd have to actually try it to be sure). There's probably a better way to handle this overall. Where is this data kept?

Comment: it's all just on my computer

Comment: @user3708965 LOL. Yes, but in what format? You should be using a database for this - and in a properly structured database, the required list of genres, sub-genres, etc. could be exported directly, without the need for all this dancing.

Comment: hahaha -- sorry sorry, i KNEW that that wasn't precisely what you were asking, I just wasn't sure what you were asking! It's all in a BIG xml file linked to an xsd file that I wrote

Comment: @user3708965 Even in an XML file, you could (and IMHO should) use cross-references, so that you have a separate "table" of genres (with nesting, something similar to what is being produced here), and each movie is linked to its genres by listing their unique ids.

Comment: I don't doubt it. I'm making a lot of this up as I go along, and learning how I should be doing things by doing it wrong! the book I got from the library hadn't mentioned that was a possibility, but I will look into it for sure.